# Usar regla remote de jquery validate [Rails 5]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

Estoy queriendo usar jquery validate para validar que el dni que se ingrese al crear una persona sea unico.
Mi formulario es (dejo solo el campo del dni):

```
<%= form_for @persona, :html => {id: 'form_personas'} do |form| %>  
  <%= form.label :dni, 'DNI (*)' %>
  <%= form.text_field :dni, class: "form-control", required: true %>    
<% end %>`
```

Reglas de jquery validate

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#form_personas').validate({  
      rules: {  
        'persona[dni]': {   
              remote:    
                      {  
                        url: 'dni_unico',  
                        type: 'get',  
                        data: {  
                          dni: $('#persona[dni]').val()  
                        }    
                      }    
            }  
    });    

</script>
```

El metodo que uso en el controlador personas es:

```
 def dni_unico  
   @existe_dni =  Persona.exists?(dni: params[:persona][:dni])  
      respond_to do |format|  
        format.json { render json: @existe_dni}  
      end  
 end
```

Routes
`get 'dni_unico', to: 'personas#dni_unico', as: :dni_unico`

El error que me figura es:
`Couldn't find Persona with 'id'=dni_unico`

```
Request parameters
{"persona"=>{"dni"=>"20156540"},
 "dni"=>"20156540",
 "id"=>"dni_unico"}
```

No entiendo por que me busca por id y envia el nombre del metodo. 
Alguien me puede dar una mano?

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que el error te lo está entregando la validación remota. Nunca he usado esa librería, pero podrías probar algo como esto:

```
$('#form_personas').validate({  
  rules: {  
    'persona[dni]': {   
      remote: {  
        url: 'dni_unico/' + $('#persona[dni]').val()
      }    
    }  
});
```

En tu archivo de rutas

`get 'dni_unico/:dni', to: 'personas#dni_unico', as: :dni_unico`

Y en tu controlador:

```
def dni_unico  
  render json: Persona.exists?(dni: params[:dni])  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue la siguiente:
Cambie mi ruta por:
`resources :personas do
    collection do
        get 'dni_unico'
    end
  end`

Y funciono. Hacia falta aclarar que es un collection